# Good library/libraries for datastructures in assembler

Tags: data-structures, assembly

Are there any good libraries (preferably with commented source) for standard datastructures (Linked list, array list, queue, stack etc.) for x86 (or others)
in Assembler ?
I don't like to reinvent (and debug !) the wheel....

Answer (score 2):

Why not just find a good C library and call it from your asm?

Or if you need "inline" functionality:

- Compile the functions you want to use into a Hello World program.
- Disassemble the program.
- Rewrite the assembly as asm/pre-processor macros.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best asking in one of the Assembler-specific groups rather than here. Try:

- the recently-released [MASM32 SDK v10](http://www.masm32.com/) which gives a link to the [MASM Forum](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php).
- the [WinAsm](http://www.winasm.net/) site.

Google said there were some data structures demo-ed on Microsoft's [MASM Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t13a3526(VS.80).aspx) page, but I didn't go hunting.

Another possibility is to check out [HLA](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AsmTools/HLA/index.html), the High Level Assembly Language. The blurb there is, in part,

> Now you can enjoy all of the benefits of high-level and low-level languages, all rolled into a single language! HLA, the High-Level Assembler lets you write true low-level code while enjoying the benefits of high-level language programming. Don't let the name fool you; you can do anything with HLA that you can do with a traditional low-level assembler. All the same instructions are present, all the same low-level programming facilities are present. The difference between HLA and low-level assemblers is that you're not stuck using low-level programming paradigms when they're not needed. Watch your productivity soar when using HLA; and write far more efficient programs than you could using high-level languages.

IIRC, their support for data structures is quite good.